# WordPress, code in html editor or code in index.php?

Tags: wordpress

I'm volunteering to create a website and i've come across this dilemma with WordPress.  Say the client deletes or edits a Page/Post in the visual editor, that could remove html code in the html editor.

The solution i've thought is to have text only in a Post, the html will be in index.php and the Page/Post will be fetched from index.php.

But for a particular page i have 30 pieces of text each inside an element with different colors.  Would it be wise to fetch each individual Post from index.php or is there another way to prevent html code from being removed?

I'd like to point out, the client doesn't know anything about HTML, so i'd like to make it as easy as possible for them, simple editing of text and images.  I don't want them to edit something in the future and the code is gone.

How do you WordPress developers approach this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this level of control, it is often helpful to use post 'custom fields'. This is pretty simple, it is a selectable field in the top dropdown when you are in the page/post editor.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

You can then access the custom fields in your php files using the get_post_custom() function.

Here's more detail: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: Thanks, how many times does it go into the database to fetch these custom fields or does it just fetch all at once and only show what i choose?

Comment: Well, that function `get_post_custom()` will return them all, then you can manipulate them in php. They are `key-value pairs`, so you'll retrieve your key (if it exists, retrieve key/value) and echo the value or include it in you php otherwise.